# unable to pause bootstrap carousel in slid or slide event

Tags: bootstrap-5

using the latest bootstrap 5 carousel, I am unable to pause the carousel from inside a slid or slide event.

```
const myCarouselEl = document.getElementById('carousel-large-background')
myCarouselEl.addEventListener('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
       var carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarouselEl, {
             interval: false
       })
})
```

I have tried a variety of different solutions and am able to pause the carousel from the document.ready body, but not inside the slid or slide event.
I wonder if it might be a scope issue, and that the slid event handler has a different scope, but when I console.log(self) inside the event handler, it returns 'window'.
Any help gratefully accepted.
Cheers.

Comment: I am sure it must be an event scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

Any code relating to the bootstrap carousel should go inside a `$(window).on('load'...)` instead of `$(document).ready(...)`
otherwise any reference that you obtain to the carousel will be null, and calling methods will not work.